# ubuntu 22.04.2 server autoinstall package install

Tags: server, offline

how do i install package without internet connection in ubuntu server autoinstall?
i need to install openbox in ubuntu without internet.

i tried to download all packages using these command: `apt download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances --no-pre-depends openbox:amd64 | grep "^\w");` but i cant install all of them. i tried to install using these commands in target device: `dpkg -i *.deb`, `apt install --no-download *.deb`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 22.04.2 server.

Comment: Please use edit and add that info to the question not as a comment.

Comment: I'am edited title. Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information about what you are trying to do.  Maybe you can post your autoinstall file.  Are you booting a custom ISO with all these packages added to it?